# how to install notify2 module in python 3.5 with my MAC computer?

Tags: python, notifications

tried the following command in the terminal,

```
$ pip3 install notify2


Collecting notify2
  Using cached notify2-0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/hgx7qkc14dsglj7724_9m5780000gn/T/pip-build-0aoqwq0g/notify2/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        import notify2
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/hgx7qkc14dsglj7724_9m5780000gn/T/pip-build-0aoqwq0g/notify2/notify2.py", line 38, in <module>
        import dbus
    ImportError: No module named 'dbus'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fr/hgx7qkc14dsglj7724_9m5780000gn/T/pip-build-0aoqwq0g/notify2/
```

So, it seems like I need to install `dbus` module first. So, I tried

```
$ pip3 install dbus
Collecting dbus
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bus
```

tried which pip

```
$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip
```

And does anyone know what shall I do?

Comment: I know there is a way to save a module in the python3.5 folder, and you can simply use it there. So, is there a way to download the dbus-python 1.2.4 and save it somewhere so that I can use import dbus in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `dbus` using `brew install dbus` and then `pip install dbus-python`

Comment: don't change a thing. Same problem persists.